# Checking the equality of lists in foreach loop - C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check the equality of 2 lists of string but it's not working. This is what I have done:

```
foreach (List<string> q in questions)
{
       if (!groupOfQuestions.Except(q).Any()) //I also tried without '!'
       {
             questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
       }
}
```

And declaration of lists:

```
List<List<string>> questions = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> groupOfQuestions = new List<string>();
```

Comment: What means "it's not working"? **Edit** i see, you want to modify the collection during enumeration, that is not allowed. Can you explain what you really want to do, maybe there is a better approach. What is the desired result?

Comment: Are you trying to check if two lists of strings contain all the same values?

Comment: I'm trying to check if 2 lists of string contain same strings regardless of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify collection within *foreach* loop, but you can do it in *for* loop:

```
  for (int i = questions.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    List<string> q = questions[i];

    if (!groupOfQuestions.Except(q).Any()) //I also tried without '!'
      questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
  }
```

Another possibility is to loop on *collection's copy*:

```
  // Note ".ToList()"
  foreach (List<string> q in questions.ToList())
    if (!groupOfQuestions.Except(q).Any()) //I also tried without '!'
       questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
```

Comment: Second solution suits me but in this way it would add groupOfQuestions as many times as there is different list of strings already in questions. How can I make to add it just once.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on this line:

```
questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
```

You cannot modify a collection while you are iterating over it.

You're going to need to create a new `List<List<string>>` that you can add the matches to. For example:

```
            var questions = new List<List<string>> { 
                new List<string>{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"},
                new List<string>{"aaa", "bbb", "ddd"},
            };
            var groupOfQuestions = new List<string>() { "ddd" };
            var questionMatches = new List<List<string>>();

            foreach (List<string> q in questions)
            {
                if (!groupOfQuestions.Except(q).Any()) //I also tried without '!'
                {
                    questionMatches.Add(groupOfQuestions);
                }
            }
```

Comment: True, but what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

`questions` can not be modified when iterating over it in a foreach. Build a new list and run `AddRange` at the end:

```
var listsToAdd = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (List<string> q in questions)
{
   if (!groupOfQuestions.Except(q).Any())
   {
       questions.Add(groupOfQuestions);
   }
}

questions.AddRange(listsToAdd);
```